# Angular form with boolean option value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form with options as text and values as boolean. Trying to implement a quiz form as follows, where there may be more than one correct option per question. The correct answer doesn't seem to get selected. My model looks like:

```
export interface Option {
  text: string;
  correct: boolean;
}
type Options = Option[];


<div class="radio-options" *ngFor="let option of question.options; let i = index">
    <mat-radio-button
      class="option"
      name="option-radio-button"
      [value]="option['correct']"
      [class.is-correct]="isCorrect(option['correct'])"
      [class.is-incorrect]="isIncorrect(option['correct'])">

      <li>{{ option.text }}</li>
      <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="isCorrect(option['correct'])">done</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="isIncorrect(option['correct'])">clear</mat-icon>
    </mat-radio-button>
```

and in my ts file:

```
isCorrect(correctval: boolean): boolean {
  return correctval === this.question.options['correct'];
}

isIncorrect(correctval: boolean): boolean {
  return correctval !== this.question.options['correct'];
}
```

Comment: Could you please make a stackbitz demo?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app

Comment: Getting routing error on StackBlitz

Comment: changed it from forChild to forRoot, and then back to forChild

Comment: There should be a way of doing this without creating an additional "selected" field on the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your StackBlitz shows Option is interface with property correct: boolean.
While Question has property options: Option[] - an array of Option objects.

So you'd reference that in the template like:

```
option.correct
```

And pass the index with a new property of selected to store if selected to compare to correct:

```
 <div class="radio-options" *ngFor="let option of question.options; let i = index">
        <mat-radio-button
          class="option"
          name="option-radio-button"
          [value]="i"
          (change)="setSelected(i)"
          [class.is-correct]="option.selected && option.correct)"
          [class.is-incorrect]="option.selected && !option.correct">
```

ts:

```
    setSelected(index)
{
     question.options.forEach(o => o.selected = false);
     question.options[i].selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the change to my function calls, but am getting all correct answers shown and correct answer doesn't seem to select.

Comment: Well can you post your changes to the StackBlitz?

Comment: I made the changes to the Stackblitz. Not sure why it isn't loading...

Comment: If you are passing option.correct and then comparing against the value if correct in the same item, they will always be true. What behaviour do you want?

Comment: would like it so that if the answer is correct the correct answer is selected only, but if an incorrect answer is chosen then the incorrect answer is red and the correct answer is green

Comment: So by default , all radios should not be selected then when one is selected it is checked against the corrcect property of that option?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without creating a selected variable?

Comment: "correct: true" should only be on the correct answer(s), no need to mark the others as false

Comment: Actually, without looking into it more, storing in selected property should work well. See edits. Might be other way but won't have chance to look into.

Comment: You need to store the selected value for checking.if correct or not.

Comment: Ok, I've made the changes locally and to Stackblitz. In theory I think it should work without creating an additional selected field and should be inferred instead. Thanks for your help.